# Does Bluemix provide API to access MQA metrics

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I have integrated my mobile applications (android/ iOS) with bluemix MQA and we are able to view the metrics in the bluxmix dashboard/ console.

Is there any API exposed from Bluemix to access these metrics of our application so that it can be displayed as part of our custom UI?

Comment: We don't have any API exposed to integrate the metrics within the app itself. What type of integration did you have in mind?

Comment: We are creating an applications which displays metrics of our organizations applications from different sources e,g, App Annie, bluemix, etc... So I see Bluemix provides rest based API's to insert data to Mobile data and other services, so exploring whether something similar exists to retrieve MQA metrics. Based on your response API are not available for MQA.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any API exposed to integrate the metrics within the app itself at this time.